# How do you add decimals to a nvarchar data type for a SQL table? Table has letters and numbers which is why it's nvarchar type

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

Table 1 has a column `diagnosis_codes` and the codes have numbers, letters, and decimals. Example `N92.6` or `Z32.01`.

Table 2 has a column `codes`, imported from an Excel file, and the format of the codes didn't have decimal points for this table. EXAMPLE `N926` & `Z3201` - same codes from Table 1 minus the decimal point.

I want to be able to add decimals, (i think decimal 10,2) to Table 2 column `Codes` that way when I do any join script to compare Table 1 column `diagnosis_codes` to Table 2 column codes they would match.

Comment: How would your SQL code know that N926 is N92.6 and not N9.26?  Or are you saying that a diagnostic code has two digits to the left of the decimal point?  It might be easier to strip the decimal points from the table 1 column in your WHERE clause.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to remove the decimal points from Table1 (if this wouldn't create a conflict)?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc the diagnostic code could have 2 or 3 digit/letters to the left of the decimal point. First character is always a letter. The second and third characters can be letters or numbers. If the code is only three characters, the decimal is not used.  The right of the decimal could have 4 characters numbers and letters

Comment: @tinazmu well I thought about that as well but the codes with the decimals are in fact the correct way to display the code. So I want to convert the whole table that has the codes without decimals to have a decimal based on the information I posted a few minutes ago if its possible. Ed gave me a script below that I can do for specific codes but would like to do the whole table.

Comment: To update the entire table with the correct `code` you need to know what the correct one is. Given, say N926, as @GilbertLeBlanc asked, how would we know that this is N9.26 or N.92.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of **string** functions can able to achieve this requirement.

assuming these are your column values:

```
declare @var1 varchar(30) = 'N92.6'
declare @var2 varchar(30) = 'N926'
```

This query will force `@var2` to format same with `@var1`. So you can use this on your `where` clause.

```
select concat(substring(@var2, 0, charindex('.', @var1)), '.', substring(@var2, charindex('.', @var1), len(@var1)-charindex('.', @var1)+1))
```

updating the actual data on the table, you can just replace `dot(.)` with empty string

```
update table1 set column1 = replace(column1, '.', '')
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement this to the whole table without the decimals? Without having to do it per code essentially?

Comment: @AshleyDaniel, `update table1 set column1 = replace(column1, '.', '')`